# json subdocuments in ember data model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a web service that returns something like this, where there is a fixed envelope and then a body that is json with a schema that depends on "body_schema".   I'd like to be able to use ember-data to manage these, with first class fields for the fixed envelope and just an object for the body field.   Is this possible?  I can't seem to see anything like this in the docs but I can't imagine I'm the first with this issue.

```
{"messages":
[
  {"id":"5",
   "from": "someone",
   "to": "somebody",
   "body_schema": "atype", 
   "body": {
     {"url":"http://localhost:3030/blobs/511d63ddd0a6b5e863000001"}
   }
  }
]}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this - what you need to do is add your own attribute transform to the existing set of JSONTransforms.   I defined an object transform like this in my app.js:

```
DS.JSONTransforms.object = {
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
      return Em.isNone(serialized) ? {} : serialized;
    },
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
      return Em.isNone(deserialized) ? {} : deserialized;
    }
};
```

With this in place, I can define a messages model like this:

```
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
  timestamp: DS.attr('date'),
  body: DS.attr('object'),
  ...
});
```

Comment: Hello,

@outside2344 I ran into the same problem and implemented the same kind of solution but when editing the data, ember data doesn't see my field as being dirty. Is this a problem you ran into as well and were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

with ember-data 1.0beta:

```
App.RawTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(serialized) {
    return serialized;
  },
  serialize: function(deserialized) {
    return deserialized;
  }
});
```

ex.

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
    bar: attr('raw'),
})
```

see https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md