# Ember data subdocuments

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Other questions on this topic are [over 3 years old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972985/json-subdocuments-in-ember-data-model).

I see this [documentation on serializers](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html), which seems like the answer, but I can't get it to work. I just want a simple JSON object structure like this:

```
business-hours : {
    monday: {
        open: “24hr”,
        from: <some time>,
        to: <some time>
    },
    tuesday: {
        open: “closed”,
        from: <some time>,
        to: <some time>
    }
},
```

What's the move here?

**Edit:** as for editing keys in an empty DS.attr() field, in response to locks' request for more information. I pass this component the model:

```
<h3>Business Hours</h3>
{{business-hours model=model}}
```

And attempt to edit the model.businessHours attribute in order to create this ideal record outlined above:

```
{{input type="time" value=model.businessHours.friday.from}}
{{input type="time" value=model.businessHours.friday.to}}
```

Should this type of syntax be allowing me to form the appropriate 'subdocument' in the model? With the empty DS.attr() field?

Comment: DS.attr() will preserve whatever data in under a key, is that not enough?

Comment: So before I save the record I should just set model.businessHours equal to an object created in the route and altered with inputs? Because it doesn't seem like you can set businessHours.monday.open directly from an input value if it's only defined with an empty DS.attr()

Comment: You should be able to. Can you edit your post and add that code?

Comment: thanks for the comments locks. I added more relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit these *subdocuments* you should use an model for this.

So for this you have two models:

/models/business-hour-week.js
    import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  monday: DS.hasMany('business-hour-day'),
  tuesday: DS.hasMany('business-hour-day')
});
```

/models/business-hour-day
    import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  open: DS.attr('string'),
  from: DS.attr('date'),
  to: DS.attr('date')
});
```

And then use a serializer to convert your data to a valid JSONAPI Document like this:

```
    {
    data: {
        type: 'business-hour-week',
        id: '1',
        relationshops: {
            monday: {
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    open: '24hr',
                    from: '<some time>',
                    to: '<some time>',
                }
            },
            toesday: {
                data: {
                    id: '1',
                    open: 'closed',
                    from: '<some time>',
                    to: '<some time>',
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this and work with it as expected.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. Using a serializer to add the ids seems hackery. This is one of those things that should be easy... These are my two solutions to the problem.

1. This is the easiest. You can use an addon called ember fragments: https://github.com/lytics/ember-data-model-fragments. This allows you to create nested models, without forcing child records to have an id. Fragment models are set up just like normal ones, and have clean/dirty attrs.
2. You can set up the 2 models as described above (week/days), but you would use a belongsTo, instead of a hasMany (single record vs array of records.) You would also have to create serializers for each parent model (week, and whatever parent it lies under) and use the embedded records mixin, setting the relationship attrs to "deserialize: records, serialize: records". You just have to make sure each models response from the server has its own id in the hierarchy. If you are using Mongo/Mongoose, you can create the sub-docs by nesting child schemas, vs using object literal syntax. This way each sub-doc gets it's own id, even if it's a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Please check this[URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your content quality up